# Is Tomcat version 7 fully ready for production

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I have a few modular and to some extend a little bit complex applications running perfectly on Apache Tomcat 6.0.32.

All of them are live except one, and I was thinking this would be a perfect time to make the switch to Tomcat 7.

I have not dig in too much in yet, but a simple trial test ran fine, and the selenium test suite runs fine too. 
Is there something I should be aware of/start worrying about or can I just start rolling out the new version of Tomcat in production now ?

There's going to be some heavy data processing load dispatching involved, but not so many concurrent users.

Suggestions ? Comments ?

*Note: I would like to hear some stories/feedback from the trenches, like am I going to get some performance decreases in some specific cases, is memory management working as good as claimed etc ... that kind of production questions.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The previous company I worked for have been successfully running 7.0.8 (while I was still there) on production, for about 5 months now already, no problems.

Comment: Approximately, what were the load and memory usage for that application. Along with a vague idea on the number of concurrent users ... if you don't mind sharing.

Comment: I actually don't have the stats anymore, since I've left them a while ago. But if I had to guess, server load I would place in the moderate level, while one customer had about 6000 users (so probably around 100 concurrent).

Answer (score 1):

yes you can,

Because tomcat 7 is a stable release and current version is Tomcat 7.0.19

It implements Servlet 3.0, JSP 2.2, and EL 2.2 specifications.

Comment: Being a 'stable' release in the eyes of its developers and being ready for production use are two completely different things.

Comment: @EJP Stable means ready for production. Beta Means it's for testing.

Comment: @EJP That might apply to a 7.0.0 release, but no longer after 19 patch levels and more than a year after the initial version.

Comment: what EJP said is still true no matter what version number. If something is called stable doesn't mean that it is stable. There might be bugs and quirks that does not matter most environments but some.

Answer (score 0):

I do not upgrade production servers unless I need a feature provided with newer version or there is some security bug. So rolling Tomcat 7 just for sake of new version makes no sense. I also found the new version less structured. If I could extract Jasper from 6.x quite easily, it was a bit more complicated for 7.x due more dependencies, so I can conclude that new codebase is lacking in quality.